# mask or filter a dataframe (containing strings) using a second dataframe with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2. They have the same shape. Here's what they look like:

df1

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | 1% | 0% |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | 1% | 0% |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | 1% | 0% |

df2

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | word | thing | NaN | NaN |
| string | word | thing | NaN | NaN |
| string | word | thing | NaN | NaN |

I want to use df2 to mask or filter df1, such that "new_df1" looks like the below. In places where df2 has "NaN', I want df1 to have NaN. In places where df2 is not NaN, I want to keep the original value of df1.

new_df1

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | NaN | NaN |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | NaN | NaN |
| 20% | 10% | 5% | NaN | NaN |

I've found functions like `df1.mask(df2=None)`, `df1.mask(df2!=None)`, `df1.where(df2!=None)`, and `df1.where(df2=None)`. I either get a dataframe full of NaN or the opposite of what I want (NaN's in new_df1 where there is a value in df2). I suspect it's because the values in df1 are strings and not integers or floats? It looks like `df.mask()` and `df.where()` don't take string exceptions, and I can't find what the right function is, but it must exist. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
new_df1 = df1.mask(df2.isnull())
```

Or you can also do:

```
new_df1 = df1.where(~df2.isnull())
```

Comment: Sadly, the first suggestion just gives me a dataframe full of NaN, and the second gives the opposite of I want. In other words, it's the same as the results I've gotten. :(

Comment: It might be because of the difference of NaN and None, please try:

`new_df1 = df1.mask(pd.isnull(df2))`

Comment: That also gives a df full of NaN. If I throw a `~` before the pd, then I get the opposite of what I want. I tried `df1.where(pd.isnull(df2))` without and with the `~`, and still the same two outputs. It's so frustratingly close. I don't think this should be necessary, but maybe I need to make an inverse of df2 (put NaN where I want to keep original values). Still, I can't image why I'd have to do it that way.

Comment: Yes, it is strange, it works on my computer but I might not have the same data types.  What do you get if you try `print(df2.dtypes)` and `print(type(df2.iloc[0,4])`

Comment: Really? Hm that's odd.

Comment: contains objects and float64;
dtype: object;
class: `str`

Comment: Are the NaN stored as strings? for example if you run `print(df2['4'] == 'NaN')` do you get any trues?

Comment: No, I get False for the column and it reports `dtype:bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the mask is aligned by index, you may need to reset the index of the two dataframes before doing the masking

Input

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[.1,.2], [.4,.5]], index=[1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',None], [None,'d']], index=[3,4])
```

Masking without aligning the index gives wrong result

```
df1.mask(df2.isnull())

    0   1
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
```

While resetting the index first gives correct result

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True).mask(df2.reset_index(drop=True).isnull())

    0   1
0   0.1 NaN
1   NaN 0.5
```

Comment: Wow that was it! It wasn't my index names, but there was one column header that was off. So I renumbered the columns, and now it works. Unbelievable. Thank you!!